# Resizing browser impacts animation - CSS

Tags: html, css, animation, browser, resize

I have the following HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>


<link rel= "stylesheet" href = "style.css"></a>
<body>

    <div class = "wrapper">
        '<img src="compsci_coffee_blend_1.png" height = 150px width = 150px class = "coffee">

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

where style.css is:

```
    position: relative;
}

.coffee{
    animation-name: slide; /*tells image which set of keyframes to take one */
    animation-duration: 2s; /*how long animation should take */
}


/* define keyframe animation */
@keyframes slide{
    from{transform: translateX(0);} /*start at 0 */
    to {transform:translateX(900px);} 
}
```

This works fine, and the image moves across the screen.
However, when I make the window of my browser smaller, the image still moves across the length of the browser at full-screen, so it gets cut off and you can't see it.
How can I fix this?
(e.g. how can I make the animation scale to the browser size?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use percentage %:

```
@keyframes slide{
from{transform: translateX(0);} /*start at 0 */
to {transform:translateX(80%);}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this. i added here animation width 100 window width

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>


<link rel= "stylesheet" href = "style.css"></a>
<body>

    <div class = "wrapper">
        '<img src="compsci_coffee_blend_1.png" height = 150px width = 150px class = "coffee">

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
  .wrapper{  
    position: relative;
}

.coffee{
    animation-name: slide; /*tells image which set of keyframes to take one */
    animation-duration: 2s; /*how long animation should take */
}


/* define keyframe animation */
@keyframes slide{
    from{transform: translateX(0);} /*start at 0 */
    to {transform: translateX(calc(100vw - 160px));} 
}
```